# OpenCV(4.3.0): error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'GaussianBlur'

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, imread, gaussianblur

I am new to OpenCV. I am trying to apply a Gaussian filter to the images. The below java code is working fine for one image but for all other images in the same or other location in my machine, it is throwing an error.

```
  static int width = 49;
  static int height = 49;

public static void gausianBlur(){

            try {
                long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                nu.pattern.OpenCV.loadShared();

                File f = new File("/Users/shankysharma/Desktop/login.png");
                   System.out.println("is file exists?: " +  f.exists() + " path: " + f.getAbsolutePath());


                //Reading the Image from the file and storing it in to a Matrix object
                Mat src = Imgcodecs.imread(f.getAbsolutePath());
                //Creating an empty matrix to store the result
                //Mat dst = new Mat();
                Mat dst = new Mat(src.rows(), src.cols(), src.type());
                System.out.println(src + " rows: " + src.rows());
                Imgproc.GaussianBlur(src, dst,new Size(width, height), 0);
                Imgcodecs.imwrite(gausian_output + "_" + width + "x" + height + ".png", dst);
                long endTme = System.currentTimeMillis();
                System.out.println("Image processed for gausian blur. Total time : " + (endTme-startTime) + " milliseconds");


            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error:" + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

**Output:**

```
is file exists?: true path: /Users/shankysharma/Desktop/login.png
Mat [ -1*-1*CV_8UC1, isCont=false, isSubmat=false, nativeObj=0x7fa6f9c16030, dataAddr=0x0 ] rows: 0
Error:cv::Exception: OpenCV(4.3.0) /Users/jason/Projects/openpnp/opencv/opencv/opencv-4.3.0/modules/imgproc/src/smooth.dispatch.cpp:606: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'GaussianBlur'
```

I am using opencv maven library:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openpnp</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0-3</version>
        </dependency>
```

There seems to be an issue while loading the image (`Mat src = Imgcodecs.imread(f.getAbsolutePath());`) as `src` matrix is not getting created. but not sure what is the root cause. I have checked the name and location of the image, those are fine.

Comment: Please read [mre]. You don’t even show where `file` is declared or what value it has! Also please add a tag for the language you’re using.

Comment: Thank you @CrisLuengo for pointing it out. I have updated the question. Please let me know if it is still missing anything.